# How can I output a list of commands sorted by user?

Tags: bash, awk, scripting

I'm trying to have a list of processes that were run sorted by the user who ran them. i have an input file that looks like this:

```
1 UID PID PPID C STIME TTY TIME CMD
2 adz110 5344 5334 0 08:47 pts /2 00:00:00 bash
3 dmq292 6908 6854 0 Jun04 pts /1 00:00:00 bash
4 adz110 7227 7150 0 Jul11 pts /9 00:00:00 who
5 erg474 7466 7461 0 08:54 pts /10 00:00:00 ls
6 dmq292 7966 7960 0 Jun04 pts /13 00:00:00 assign1 . sh if of
7 xle135 8983 8636 0 08:59 pts /15 00:00:00 ssh ctf . cs . utsarr . net
8 zeh458 9057 1980 0 08:59 pts /7 00:00:00 vim prog . c
9 rslavin 9150 9139 0 08:59 pts /16 00:00:00 ps - af
10 xle135 8636 8628 0 08:58 pts /15 00:00:00 bash
```

Unfortunately I'm unable to use any options of the sort command for this assignment. I can use sort, just no options. Primarily, I'll have to use awk for this. I have the output pretty close to how I need it, just not quite there. This is how it prints out:

```
User: adz110
       bash
User: dmq292
       bash

User: erg474
       ls

User: xle135
       ssh
User: zeh458
       vim
User: rslavin
       ps
```

So, it no longer lists adz110, dmq292, and xle135 twice. However, the second command that each user ran is not there. Tinkering around with it, I did get it to print out that information, but it was the whole line and it would print out one user below where I needed it.

```
gawk '/^[a-z]/ { if(!x[$1]++) print "User: "($1)"\n\t""   "$8; else if(x[$1]++) print "\t   "x[$NF] };
```

'

This was supposed to be the end result:

```
User : adz110
2           bash
3           who
4 User : dmq292
5           bash
6 assign1 . sh if of
7 User : erg474
8           ls
9 User : xle135
10          bash
11          ssh ctf . cs . utsarr . net
12 User : zeh458
13          vim prog . c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following(using `sort` + `awk` combination).

***EDIT1:*** As per Ed sir's nice  advice, I am adding following command which will make sure in case timings are coming inside command it should NOT remove them.

Let's consider following is the Input_file:

```
cat Input_file
1 UID PID PPID C STIME TTY TIME CMD
2 adz110 5344 5334 0 08:47 pts /2 00:00:00 bash
3 dmq292 6908 6854 0 Jun04 pts /1 00:00:00 bash
4 adz110 7227 7150 0 Jul11 pts /9 00:00:00 who
5 erg474 7466 7461 0 08:54 pts /10 00:00:00 ls
6 dmq292 7966 7960 0 Jun04 pts /13 00:00:00 assign1 . sh if of
7 xle135 8983 8636 0 08:59 pts /15 00:00:00 ssh ctf . cs . utsarr . net
8 zeh458 9057 1980 0 08:59 pts /7 00:00:00 vim prog . c
9 rslavin 9150 9139 0 08:59 pts /16 00:00:00 ps - af
10 xle135 8636 8628 0 08:58 pts /15 00:00:00 bash
4 adz110 7227 7150 0 Jul11 pts /9 00:00:00 grep 'pts /7 '11:00 foo'
4 adz110 7227 7150 0 Jul11 pts /9 00:00:00 grep 1 UID PID PPID C STIME TTY TIME CMD
```

Now code is as follows:

```
sort -k2 Input_file | 
awk '
$0 ~ /^1 UID PID PPID C STIME TTY TIME CMD$/{
  next
}
prev!=$2 && prev{
  print "user:   " prev ORS "\t" val
  prev=val=""
}
{
  prev=$2
  match($0,/[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9].*/)
  match_val=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  val=(val?val ORS "\t":"")match_val
}
END{
  if(prev){
    print "user:   " prev ORS "\t" val
  }
}'
```

Output will be as follows:

```
user:  adz110
        bash
        grep 1 UID PID PPID C STIME TTY TIME CMD
        grep 'pts /7 '11:00 foo'
        who
user:  dmq292
        bash
        assign1 . sh if of
user:  erg474
        ls
user:  rslavin
        ps - af
user:  xle135
        bash
        ssh ctf . cs . utsarr . net
user:  zeh458
        vim prog . c
```

---

---

```
sort -k2 Input_file | 
awk '
$0 ~ /UID PID PPID C STIME TTY TIME CMD/{
  next
}
prev!=$2 && prev{
  print "user:   " prev ORS "\t" val
  prev=val=""
}
{
  prev=$2
  sub(/.*:00 /,"")
  val=(val?val ORS "\t":"")$0
}
END{
  if(prev){
    print "user:   " prev ORS "\t" val
  }
}'
```

Output will be as follows.

```
user:   adz110
        bash
        who
user:   dmq292
        bash
        assign1 . sh if of
user:   erg474
        ls
user:   rslavin
        ps - af
user:   xle135
        bash
        ssh ctf . cs . utsarr . net
user: zeh458
      vim prog . c
```

Comment: Consider what `sub(/.*:00 /,"")` would do if one of the commands listed at the end of one of the lines in the input file was `grep '11:00'` or similar. Also consider what would happen if it contained `grep 'UID PID PPID C STIME TTY TIME CMD'`. It's always safer to test for positions like the Nth line or the Nth column rather than content that happens to be present or not in the sample input.

Comment: @EdMorton, Sure Ed sir. What I thought is, time stamp will always be HH:MM:SS format and always will be same in output so I had written it, sorry I didn't consider that it may differ too, can it happen, looks like it is output of a command.

Comment: Looks like `ps` output to me. Anyway, the problem isn't that the timestamp format may vary (though thinking about that now I can't see why it'd **always** be exactly `00:00:00`), it's that the command at the end of the line may also contain text that's in the same format as the timestamp. Try your solution of the 4th line of input was changed to `4 adz110 7227 7150 0 Jul11 pts /9 00:00:00 grep '11:00 foo'`. The way you're filtering out the header line has the same problem - that exact text might be part of one of the end of line commands in the list.

Comment: @EdMorton, Brilliant Ed sir, Thank a TON for letting me know, how can be you so perfect sir :) I added an EDIT solution now, please feel free to correct me or improve my solution sir, cheers.

Comment: You're welcome but you still have the same problems in the edited version.

Comment: @EdMorton, You mean to say pts may also come in command's details sir?

Comment: Right. Why not? There's no reason to assume the input cannot contain a line that ends with `grep "pts /7 12:13:14 foo"`

Comment: @EdMorton, Sure sir, I changed approach a bit now, how about now sir, kindly do let me know.

Comment: Seems like it'd work but you could get rid of the `sub()` by just doing `match($0,/[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] /); match_val=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)`

Comment: @EdMorton, sure sir thank you, have corrected it now, cheers.

Comment: Again, though, I personally would favor using the positions of the data you want to extract rather than the values of the data.

Comment: @EdMorton, To be honest sir, my `awk` is old one even `[0-9]{2}` doesn't work there sir(I think it may, while adding `--re-interval` it may work), so I had gone for this approach, will try to upgrade it(if I am allowed to do it :) )

Comment: Right, you needed `--re-interval` prior to gawk 4.0 and we're now on gawk 5.0.1 so you are several years out of date and missing a few bug fixes and MANY useful features (see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Feature-History).

Answer (score 2):

```
$ tail +2 file | sort -k2,2 |
    awk '$2!=prev{print "User:", $2; prev=$2} {sub(/^([^ ]+ +){9}/,"\t")} 1'
User: adz110
        bash
        who
User: dmq292
        bash
        assign1 . sh if of
User: erg474
        ls
User: rslavin
        ps - af
User: xle135
        bash
        ssh ctf . cs . utsarr . net
User: zeh458
        vim prog . c
```